# Oracle SQL Developer connection issue

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to create new connection in Oracle SQL Developers but `connection failed` message occurred. It's asking for username and password, I didn't know what username and password should I provide. As I had not asked to set username and password while installing Oracle SQL Developer

Comment: SQL Developer is just a client. You need a database as well. If you're part of a wider organisation you should ask your colleagues for some guidance.  If you're on your own you need to download and install one. Maybe start with XE. [Find out more](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/express-edition/downloads/index.html)

Comment: https://medium.com/oracledevs/i-installed-oracle-sql-developer-now-what-71230b9c9303

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

Based on step 3 of "Creating a Database Connection" in this [documentation](https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/11g/r2/prod/appdev/sqldev/sqldev_mngdb/sqldev_mngdb_otn.htm) the default username is `hr` and default password is also `hr`

If that does not work, try:

- username: `SYS` and password: `change_on_install` or `CHANGE_ON_INSTALL`
- username: `SYSTEM` and password: `manager` or `MANAGER`

Comment: the HR user must be created in order to use it. the default accounts for a database are SYSTEM and SYS - which are there for admin purposes and for creating schemas for applications